# HTML and CSS codes to be together color highlighted in one .html project

Tags: html, css, notepad++, sublimetext3

I am doing HTML/CSS as beginner and when I add an simple CSS styled button code in my HTML file it won't highlight that code with an specific color. I changed in settings from HTML to CSS highlights but then it doesn't show HTML color codes but it finally shows up CSS highlighted colored codes. If you really didn't understand me, what I am about to say is like when `<a href="Website.html"` is colored with `href` as green colored code and the other one CSS code such as `.btn`, `border: none;` etc it doesn't have any color until I change it in the settings but later that `.btn` and whole CSS file have colors but HTML doesn't. If can anyone tell me if I can do something in any of these two Notepad++ or Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Can you post your complete code along with a description of what is/isn't working?

Comment: Well, you actually don't need a code, I am just asking for making the settings of Notepad++/Sublime Text 3 to make both of those codes to be together color highlighted. When I enable HTML highlight then CSS codes are all white without their code colors. When I turn CSS highlight then HTML code will be almost all white only <head></head> and code like that will be pink... I hope you understand now...

Comment: Oh gotcha, I thought you were having a CSS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime Text should be able to tell which syntax highlighting to use, if the file syntax is set to HTML. As long as your css is inside `style` tags. If it is and you're still not seeing correct highlighting, it might be an issue with your particular color scheme.

Comment: My CSS code was not in <style> tag so it was my fault after all, but without your answer I might not realise this! Thank you very much!